# Tezos Baker Daemon Stalling

Tags: baker

I am running a tezos node on my mac. My tezos node is synchronized and my baker daemon is bootstrapped but it it keeps missing blocks. When I run my baker this message shows up “ node is bootstrapped waiting for protocol alpha to start…”.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running tezos-baker-alpha … like the docs said I ran tezos-baker-013-Ptjakart

Comment: Edit your question and provide the commands on how you are executing the baker and also provide the output. Also provide a few lines of the node log output. We can't see your screen.